# calling gets after malloc (assembly NASM x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to call 'gets' function of the C library after allocating memory using malloc  (also of the C library) and I keep getting segmentation faults and I have no idea why!! 
I know something is wrong with the stack but I don't know what!
here is the code:

```
section .rodata
LC0:
    DB  "The number is: %i", 10, 0  ;  string

LC1:
    DB  "Allocation failed!!!", 10, 0   ;  string


section .data

section .bss

stack_size:
    RESB    20

section .text
    align 16
    global main
    extern printf
    extern malloc
    extern gets
    link_size EQU 5

_start:
    jmp main 

main:

    mov dword edi, link_size
    push edi
    call malloc
    mov dword [stack_size], eax

    test eax,eax
    jz fail_exit

    add esp,4

    push ecx
    call gets
    pop ecx

    ret

fail_exit:
    push LC1
    call printf
    add esp,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the fact for the moment that `gets` is a spectacularly unsafe function even when you use it properly (no way to protect against buffer overflow), your immediate problem lies here:

```
push ecx
call gets
pop ecx
```

If that `ecx` is supposed to be the buffer to read the string into, you haven't set it to anything useful. That's almost certainly why you're getting the memory fault.

The buffer returned from `malloc` was placed into `eax`, not `ecx`. I suspect that's what you want to push as the `gets` parameter.

If the memory you allocated is *not* where you want to put the characters from `gets`, you need to initialise `ecx` to some other buffer before pushing it.

Comment: I did not mean to push eax, I wanted to push ecx as the buffer, I know that the return address from the malloc is in the eax and I allready moved the result into my stack_size variable. also,intiallizing ecx dose not help solve the problem - segmentation fault.

Comment: @yair, push `ecx` as _what_ buffer exactly. You haven't actually set `ecx` to anything. `gets` requires a buffer and you appear to be giving it some random value, hence the fault. Where exactly do you wish to place the characters you get from `gets` (the buffer you just malloced seems the most logical place)? You need to initialise `ecx` to that before pushing it.

Comment: I want to place them into eax and then copy them to the buffer I malloc'ed. (return value from calling C functions is always put in EAX). And even if I intillize ECX with "mov ecx,0" or such it still gives fault.

Comment: @yair: okay, the memory address from `malloc` is in `eax`, _not_ `ecx`. So you need to push `eax` before calling `gets`. As I stated, you have not explicitly set `ecx` to anything so it's likely to be some arbitrary value unsuitable for passing to `gets`. And setting `ecx` to 0 won't help, that's the null pointer. You need to set it to point to a valid buffer of some sort.

Comment: If I delete all the part at the start then:
    push ecx
    call gets
    pop ecx                                                         works fine, and I can even print the result, how do you explain it if ECX is not treated as a buffer to begin with?

Comment: How do I explain it? I don't. Bottom line is, if you call `gets` with an uininitialised pointer, it's undefined behaviour in NASM as much as it is in C. Don't do it. Have a buffer. Push the address of that buffer. Anything else is asking for trouble. I ask again: _where_ exactly are you expecting `gets` to place the characters? It doesn't allocate its own memory, you have to give it some, and it _MUST_ be valid.

Comment: so you are saying that it worked because of unexpected behaviour and even if i call it without mallocing first its just like using an unintiallized pointer?

Comment: Yes, what you're doing is no different to `char *xyzzy; gets (xyzzy);`. Sometimes UB works (or seems to work but corrupts something else). It's still a bad idea to do it :-)

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. Just don't, it's  deprecated and horrible.

Comment: @EOF, that's good advice but not really apt for the question at hand. The much safer `fgets` would also fail if you passed a dodgy pointer to it :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sure, but `gets()` is *insane*. I'd rather try to find the reason for a segfault in a program that *doesn't* use `gets()`. Seems way less crazy.

Comment: @EOF, fair enough, I've added a preamble to the answer along those lines.